# Inmotion hosting / Symfony / session already sent

Tags: php, symfony, session

I just migrated my website to inmotion shared hosting, but I can't run my application in prod mode.

Here is a screen:

> Warning:
> include_once(/home/applet15/public_html/web/../var/bootstrap.php.cache):
> failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
> /home/applet15/public_html/web/app.php on line 9
>
> Warning: include_once(): Failed opening
> '/home/applet15/public_html/web/../var/bootstrap.php.cache' for
> inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in
> /home/applet15/public_html/web/app.php on line 9
>
> Fatal error: Uncaught RuntimeException: Failed to start the session
> because headers have already been sent by
> "/home/applet15/public_html/web/app.php" at line 9. in
> /home/applet15/public_html/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Session/Storage/NativeSessionStorage.php:134
> Stack trace: #0
> /home/applet15/public_html/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Session/Storage/NativeSessionStorage.php(259):
> Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Storage\NativeSessionStorage->start()
>
> ## 1 /home/applet15/public_html/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Session/Session.php(87):
>
> Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Storage\NativeSessionStorage->getBag('attributes')
>
> ## 2 /home/applet15/public_html/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Http/Firewall/ContextListener.php(78):
>
> Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session->get('_security_main')
>
> ## 3 /home/applet15/public_html/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Http/Firewall.php(69):
>
> Sy in
> /home/applet15/public_html/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Template.php on
> line 396

session.auto_start is set to 0

If I try to install a new SF2/3 project, everything works fine. But mine can't run in prod mode :(

Where can be a problem?

Thanks

PS: Everything works fine on another shared hosting.

Answer (score 0):

The session header must be sent before any other output. In the screenshot provided, 2 php warnings are output before the session header. Correct your code to get rid of the warnings or turn warnings off. (Ideally, amend your code so the warnings aren't raised)

Comment: There is fatal error... But this code works fine on another hosting. I changed nothing after transfer files.

Comment: Maybe warnings were turned off on the other setup. Not all servers are configured the same. You need to fix the include_once statements causing the error.

Comment: They not yet responded on my ticket, so I refunded my money back and move to A2 Hosting. Now everything works perfect :)

But thanks for advice :)